# IllegalArgumentException configuring MDB in weblogic12 using annotations

Tags: ejb-3.0, weblogic12c

My MDB code:

```
@MessageDriven(name="FOOListener",activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "initial-context-factory", propertyValue = "com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "connectionFactoryJndiName", propertyValue = "someJndiName"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationJndiName", propertyValue = "a.b.c.queue")})
public class PaymentAdviceMessageListener  implements MessageListener{

    private MessageDrivenContext mdContext = null;

    @Override
    public void setMessageDrivenContext(MessageDrivenContext mdc) throws EJBException {
        logger.log(Severity.INFO,"setMessageDrivenContext()", this.getClass().getName());
        mdContext = mdc;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message jmsMessage) {
....
```

When I start weblogic server, I get following exception:

```
<MessageDrivenBean threw an Exception in onMessage(). The exception is:
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javax.ejb.MessageDrivenContext field com.abc.fc.xxx.webservice.mq.PaymentAdviceMessageListener.mdctx to weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javax.ejb.MessageDrivenContext field com.abc.fc.xxx.webservice.mq.PaymentAdviceMessageListener.mdctx to weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:150)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:63)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:657)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldFieldImpl.set(WeldFieldImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:136)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectEEFields(Beans.java:629)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.SimpleInjectionTarget$1.proceed(SimpleInjectionTarget.java:106)
    at com.oracle.injection.provider.weld.WeldInjectionServicesAdapter.aroundInject(WeldInjectionServicesAdapter.java:89)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:45)
```

It works fine with EJB2 style depolyment descriptors. I need it to work using annotations. Please help.

Comment: Why don't you just mark `mdContext` with `@Resource` ? The container should take care of the injection.

Comment: I tried to do that as well, but getting same error